# What is the difference between syncdb and migrate?

Tags: python, django, web, frameworks

I am going through django documentation. And here I have a situation. In one of the documentation, I am told to do

```
python manage.py migrate
```

And in the other

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I can't do the first one(Error: no migrate command found.) but second works fine for me. Is this a version issue or I need to take care of something else.

Comment: could you share the documentation link you're talking about?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `migrate` belongs to an application called south (http://south.aeracode.org/).

From the website:

> This is South, intelligent schema and data migrations for ​Django projects.

Prior to Django==1.7 you had to install a third party application in order to perform database migrations.

Please see documentation at [readthedocs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 7):

The `migrate` command is new in the upcoming [Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#what-s-new-in-django-1-7), which hasn't been released yet.

For earlier versions you can use `syncdb`, or the external app [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

When you're reading the documentation, use the Documentation version switcher to select the correct version.

For example, the current [1.6 Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) uses `syncdb`, but the [dev tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) (written for the upcoming 1.7) uses `migrate`.

Comment: Thanks !! I was spending time on that. Can you tell me a little on south?? "pip install south" in virtualenv will get the package??

Comment: and yes, I tried to install the latest version by doing "pip install django==1.7".. i couldn't do that.. Can you explain me that too??

Comment: The [south docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) are better than any comment I can write here. If you get stuck, ask another question.

Comment: and what about the installation? pip install south?

Comment: django 1.7 isn't released yet. It is under development. You can install it but I wouldn't recommend it as it is not as stable as 1.6 and is subject to change.

Comment: any recommended version? @Alasdair

Comment: Yes, `pip install south` will work. I agree with Pete's advice to stick to the most recent release, currently 1.6.

Comment: `pip install South` will get you the latest stable version of South (0.8.4) anyway, so you don't need to specify a version

Answer (score 2):

It depends what version of the documentation you are reading. `migrate` is the command from [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which up until the latest (currently development, or dev) version of django was a separate app. It's finally getting integrated into Django (basically every django project uses it anyway as a matter of course, so it is well worth reading up on).

In the bottom right of the django documentation page there is a selector where you can switch between different versions of Django, so if you're looking for information for your project it is a good idea to change to the version of Django you're currently using.