# "Unknown command syncdb" running "python manage.py syncdb"

Tags: django, sqlite, python-3.x, django-1.9

I want to create the tables of one database called "database1.sqlite", so I run the command:

> python manage.py syncdb

but when I execute the command I receive the following error:

> Unknown command: 'syncdb'
>   Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

But when I run

> manage.py help

I don`t see any command suspicious to substitute

> python manage.py syncdb

Version of Python I use: 3.4.2    Version of Django I use:1.9

I would be very grateful if somebody could help me to solve this issue.

Regards and thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like you are a bit ahead of time maybe? :p Isn't django 1.8 in alpha?

Comment: have you tried `python manage.py migrate` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/)

Comment: Gracias por su apoyo. Su resuelto  @Archi --> I installed the beta version 1.9. As I am using a videotutorial to learn Django I have decided to install the same version the videotutorial is using the 1.6.2 one.

Comment: A small discussion can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402649/what-is-the-difference-between-syncdb-and-migrate

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you look at the [release notes for `django 1.9`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/), `syncdb` command is removed.

Please use `migrate` instead. Moving forward, the [migration commands would be as documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/#what-s-new-in-django-1-7)

Please note that the django-1.9 release is not stable as of today.

Edit: Django 1.9 is stable now

Comment: Thanks for your support. Solved  @Archi --> I installed the beta version 1.9. As I am using a videotutorial to learn Django I have decided to install the same version the videotutorial is using the 1.6.2 one.

Comment: how to load fixtures? before that it was very comfortable

Answer (score 8):

the new django 1.9 has removed "syncdb",
run "python manage.py migrate",
if you are trying to create a super user, run "python manage.py createsuperuser"

Answer (score 7):

`$python manage.py syncdb` is deprecated and not supported now.
So instead of this follow below instructions..

Whatever model you have created:
First run:

```
$python manage.py makemigrations
```

After running this command you model will be reflected in a migration.

Then you have to run:

```
$python manage.py migrate
```

Then run server:

```
$python manage.py runserver
```

Now, your project will run perfectly.

Comment: and what about fixture loading? it was very comfy with one command

Answer (score 2):

In Django 1.9 onwards `syncdb` command is removed. So instead of use that one, you can use `migrate` command,eg: `python manage.py migrate`.Then you can run your server by `python manage.py runserver` command.

Answer (score 1):

Django has removed `python manage.py syncdb` command now you can simply use `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by`python manage.py migrate`. The database will sync automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the only thing worked for me was this command.

```
python3 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Running this got me this result.

```
Ranvijays-Mac:djangodemo rana.singh$ python3 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: messages, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, msg, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  Applying msg.0001_initial... OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command from the project folder as: "`python.exe manage.py migrate`", from a commandline or in a batch-file.
You could also downgrade Django to an older version (before 1.9) if you really need syncdb.

For people trying to run Syncdb from Visual Studio 2015:
The option syncdb was removed from Django 1.9 (deprecated from 1.7), but this option is currently not updated in the context menu of VS2015.

Also, in case you didn't get asked to create a superuser you should manually run this command to create one: `python.exe manage.py createsuperuser`

Answer (score 0):

Run the command python manage.py makemigratons,and than python manage.py migrate to sync.

Answer (score 0):

Alternarte Way:

1. Uninstall Django Module from environment
2. Edit Requirements.txt a type Django<1.9
3. Run Install from Requirments option in the enviroment
4. Try Syncdb again

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this command. Lastly I found the release note from django

> Features removed in 1.9

The syncdb command is removed.

[Djnago Releases note 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/)

[image]